# IntelliJ on startup "compacting indices"

Tags: intellij-idea, startup, vpn, indices

Today I  have started working offsite using a vpn connection to get access to the companies network.
Unfortunately I start my work with intellij not wanting to startup.
**The splashscreen gets stuck with a loader appearing saying "compacting indices".**
Google is not helping out a lot. I'm thinking moving back to eclipse.
Has anybody experienced this problem before?
Please see attachement.[image]

Comment: do you see any exception in intellij log file ? (log file is probably here : $USER_HOME/.IntelliJIdea12/system/log/idea.log or a similar location depending on the version of IntelliJ) How long did you wait ?

Comment: Timo, how did it go? Did you see my suggestion in my answer below to manually clear the `caches` folder and force them to be rebuilt?

Comment: Could it be something to do with the proxy settings? Would you know whether you need to enable/add a proxy to get to the work network ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: File menu -> Invalidate Caches... ?

Also are you on latest and greatest, 12.1.4 ?

Or how about deleting (actually, moving them, to keep as backup) the caches manually?

```
c:\Users\{user}\.IntelliJIdea12\system\caches
```

Comment: Since IntelliJ didn't start... it's difficult to access the File menu ;-)

Comment: How about deleting (actually, move it, to keep as backup) the caches manually? c:\Users\{user}\.IntelliJIdea12\system\caches